# Use JQuery to do server side validation then send user to another site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to 'postpone' (stop the default behavior of the form) sending the user to 'http://www.othersite.com' until server side validation is finished on check.php

Once complete, send the user on their way to 'http://www.othersite.com'. I can send to the validation page no problem, but I need to validate then send to another website. Say I have a form like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#sendbutton').click(function(){
$('#error').empty();
$('#send').ajaxForm(function (data, textStatus) {
$('#error').append(data);
});
});
});

<form id="send" name="send" method="post" action="http://www.othersite.com/index.htm">
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" />
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" />
<input type="text" id="address" name="address" />
<input type="text" id="city" name="city" />
<input type="text" id="state" name="state" />
<button id="sendbutton">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="error"></div>
```

And server side validation occurs on check.php

```
check field inputs here on check.php
if not correct
echo error message

if successful echo "validation_ok"
```

If the returned data is 'validation_ok' then send the user to complete form submission on 'http://www.othersite.com'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like an excellent opportunity for AJAX (as implied by @nachito). Otherwise, you can also:

1. Have `check.php` render the form initially and do the client-side validation.
2. Have the form's action to `check.php` (effectively posting back to itself).
3. On successful validation, set the form's action to `www.othersite.com` and echo a javascript literal value (or a hidden input, if you're so inclined) flagging an "auto-submit".

   - You could also use jQuery to change the form's action, rather than flip it in `check.php`.
4. Once the flag is detected, submit the form on the `document.ready` event.

Failing that, you could also have `check.php` post to `www.othersite.com` if server-side validation has passed using `cURL` (and without, just google "[HTTP POST from PHP, without cURL](https://www.google.com/search?q=HTTP%20POST%20from%20PHP,%20without%20cURL)").

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#send').submit(function() {
        $('#error').empty();
        // Post the form to your validation page
        $.post('/check.php', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
            // If validation failed, stop submission
            if (data != 'validation_ok') {
                $('#error').append(data);
                // Prevent submission.
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The returned data is opening a new page and writing the error messages there, not in the error div. I have jquery.form.js, is that interfering with the script?

Comment: Actually it's still posting to the page set in the form's action on my test page